# Laravel Brain Socket: How to start in hosting server?

Tags: php, shell, sockets, command

I have a site setup with [Brain Socket](https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket), now i have ssh access to my hosting and have my port 8080 opened.

I have been running this command `php artisan brainsocket:start` using `screen` command in terminal to make the process goes on forever even after i close my terminal. Problem is the next day I login again the `screen` is dead and the socket server closed.

How do you properly setup a brainsocket server? I googled using `nohup` could be a solution. But I have no idea how this works, I need step by step.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but try adding this on global.php `Artisan::call(brainsocket:start);`

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is by using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) on your server and create a specific task for your `php artisan brainsocket:start` command.